# UIViewController move up when keyboard present

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have a uiviewcontroller with textfields. When clicking in the bottom text field the field is covered by the keyboard, how can i make it "scroll" up when you click in the text field. or just have it so the uiviewcontroller can scroll

Comment: Google "UIViewController move up when keyboard present"

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your all textfields of the view inside a scrollview then make your view controller conforms to **UITextFieldDelegate** and **UINavigationControllerDelegate** .

Define the following methods in your viewController.m

```
-(IBAction)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)sender // connect all textfields in your view to this method
{
    sender.delegate = self;
}
//called when UIKeyboardDidShowNotification is sent.
-(void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary * info =   [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize  kbSize  =   [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey]CGRectValue].size;
    [self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, kbSize.height) animated:YES];

}
// Called when the UIKeyboardWillHideNotification is sent,method is called when the keyboard is closed. It returns the scroll view to its original position.
- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    [self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated:YES];
}

//This method is called when you have finished editing a text field.
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    return [textField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Put this in your viewDidLoad :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];        
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = YES;
}
```

This might do the trick ... HTH :)